# PyTorch adapt binary classification model to output probabilities of both classes

Tags: python, pytorch, classification

My dataset has 14 features and a target containing {0,1}.

I have trained this binary classifier:

```py
class SimpleBinaryClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_shape,64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64,32)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.1)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32,1)
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

with the following criterion and training loop:

```py
criterion   = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

```
def binary_acc(y_pred, y_test):
    y_pred_tag = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(y_pred))
    correct_results_sum = (y_pred_tag == y_test).sum().float()
    acc = correct_results_sum/y_test.shape[0]
    acc = torch.round(acc * 100)
    
    return acc

model.train()
for e in range(1, EPOCHS+1):
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        X_batch, y_batch = X_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        y_pred = model(X_batch)
        
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y_batch.unsqueeze(1))
        acc = binary_acc(y_pred, y_batch.unsqueeze(1))
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()
        

    print(f'Epoch {e+0:03}: | Loss: {epoch_loss/len(train_loader):.5f} | Acc: {epoch_acc/len(train_loader):.3f}')
```

This model, when called like `sigmoid(model(input_tensor))` outputs a single number in [0,1]. The pipeline I'm working with, **expects a model to output probabilities [p_class1, p_class2].**

How can I adapt the model and the training loop?

If I set the output of the last layer to 2, I have problems with the criterion inside the training loop.

```py
class SimpleBinaryClassifier2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_shape,64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64,32)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.1)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32,2) # now it's 2
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

I use the CrossEntropy

```
model = SimpleBinaryClassifier2(input_shape=14)
model.to(device)
print(model)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
criterion   = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

and replace `y_pred_tag = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(y_pred))` with `argmax(softmax)`

```
def binary_acc2(y_pred, y_test):
    y_pred_tag = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(y_pred), dim=1)
    correct_results_sum = (y_pred_tag == y_test).sum().float()
    acc = correct_results_sum/y_test.shape[0]
    acc = torch.round(acc * 100)
    return acc
```

Then the train loop rises an error:

```
model.train()
for e in range(1, EPOCHS+1):
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        X_batch, y_batch = X_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        y_pred = model(X_batch)
        
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y_batch)
        acc = binary_acc(y_pred, y_batch)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()
        
​
    print(f'Epoch {e+0:03}: | Loss: {epoch_loss/len(train_loader):.5f} | Acc: {epoch_acc/len(train_loader):.3f}')
```

The error is the following:

```
RuntimeError: "nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d_index" not implemented for 'Float'
```

I already looked up on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742930/runtimeerror-nll-loss-forward-reduce-cuda-kernel-2d-index-not-implemented-for) where the cause of that error was that the element was a Float and not a tensor, but in my case the datasets are tensors:

```
train_dataset = GenericDataset(torch.FloatTensor(X_train), torch.FloatTensor(y_train))
test_dataset = GenericDataset(torch.FloatTensor(X_test), torch.FloatTensor(y_test))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` [description](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) it expects target as *long* and not *float*, while in your `train_dataset` you clearly convert it to float