# Nltk is installed but nltk_utils returns ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip, nltk, modulenotfounderror

I am using virtual env, I have installed nltk module with pip3, when I am trying to import *nltk_utils* I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import nltk_utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk_utils'
```

I have tried without virtualenv too but no luck

OS : Ubuntu

Python Version : 3.9.5

GCC : 10.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nltk_utils` is nothing that comes shipped with `nltk`. Did you mean `nltk.util`, which is [described here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.util.html)?

Otherwise `nltk_utils` is used in some examples using `nltk` where it is a custom file that contains useful functions in interacting with `nltk` (E.g. in [this chatbot example](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/chatbot-pytorch/)) so if you are following some tutorial or similar, check if they mention somewhere what `nltk_utils` should contain

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of user FlyingTeller:
I came here having the same problem, **and i followed the [exact same tutorial](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/chatbot-pytorch/)** as linked by user FlyingTeller. The referenced import "nltk_utils" is a custom file made in the scope of the tutorial.

**Solving the problem:**
You can find "nltk_utils" at the github of the tutorial creator, here:
https://github.com/patrickloeber/pytorch-chatbot/blob/master/nltk_utils.py
(for more explanation about that file, check the video that is linked in the tutorial).

**Update:**
You also need the file "model.py", which is found at the above linked github, too.
After that, you may still face errors, in my case i needed to move the "# train model" part into **main** and also cast the labels to int. The adjusted code looks as follows:

```python
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Train the model
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for (words, labels) in train_loader:
            words = words.to(device)
            labels = labels.type(torch.LongTensor) # <- Fix from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71149364/18456868
            labels = labels.to(device)

            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(words)
...
```

After that, i got it working:
[Output of script after about 3 minutes of training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUBqx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue arises possibly because you did not take the nltk_utils.py file into your directory so ensure that you have done that; I come with this reseasoning because I usually write the utility methods like tokenize, stem or bag_of_words etc into that file for modularisation